# If ${\overline{z}}^2=z^2$ where z is a complex number then z is either real or pure imaginary

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus

If ${\overline{z}}^2=z^2$ where z is a complex number then z is either real or pure imaginary

Approach: I approach this algebraically. I set $z=x+yi$ and came up with $(x^2-y^2)-2xyi=(x-y^2)+2xyi$

I see that it can't be both imaginary and real because the equality doesn't fit. It can be real, but how can it be pure imaginary?

Comment: $(yi)^{2} = (-yi)^{2}=-y^{2}$

Comment: $(x^2-y^2)-2xyi=(x-y^2)+2xyi \implies 0=4xyi \implies x = 0 \text{ or } y = 0$

Comment: Either x or y is zero.  So either imaginary (x = 0) or real (y= 0).  If x = 0 you have $(-yi)^2 = (yi)^2$.  Which is true as both = $-y^2$.

Answer (score 3):

You have found that $\bar{z}^2=z^2$ iff $-2xyi=2xyi$, which is true iff $2xy=0$.  This happens iff $x=0$ or $y=0$, which is exactly saying either $z$ is real or pure imaginary.  Explicitly, if $z=iy$ is purely imaginary, then $\bar{z}^2=(-iy)^2=(-i)^2y^2=-y^2$ and $z^2=(iy)^2=i^2y^2=-y^2$.

Answer (score 3):

${\overline{z}}^2=z^2$ iff ${\overline{z}}^2-z^2=0$ iff $({\overline{z}}-z)({\overline{z}}+z)=0$ iff $\overline{z}=\pm z$ iff $z$ is real or pure imaginary.

Answer (score 2):

$${\overline{z}}^2=z^2\implies{\overline{z}}^2z^2=z^4\implies \vert z \vert ^4 = z^4\implies z^4\in\mathbb{R}^+$$

A quick look at polar form/arguments shows that $z^4$ is a positive real iff $z$ is pure real or pure imaginary, and we are done.

Answer (score 0):

Another way: use polar form.  Write $z = re^{i \theta}, r > 0$ and $0 \leq \theta < 2\pi$.  Then $\overline{z} = re^{-i\theta}$.  By hypothesis, $$r^2e^{i2\theta} = r^2 e^{-i2\theta}$$ Hence $e^{i4\theta} = 1$. For $x$ real, $e^{ix} = 1$ if and only if $x$ is an integer multiple of $2\pi$.  So $4\theta = 2k\pi$ for some integer $k$.  Then $2\theta = k\pi$.  If $k$ is even, then $z$ is real, and if $k$ is odd, then $z$ is purely imaginary.

Comment: Couldn't you also have $e^{i2\theta}=-1$?

Comment: Thank you, yes.  I've fixed it.